# Trying to install gdal 3.0.4 on Red Hat 8

Tags: gdal, jpg, red-hat

I'm running Red Hat 8, and I'm trying to install gdal 3.0.4 on it.

The commands I've excuted thus far:

```bsh
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.0.4/gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz
tar zxvf gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz
cd gdal-3.0.4
./configure
sudo make install
```

After I run `sudo make install`, I get the following error messages:

```bsh
path/to/gdal-3.0.4/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress_12`
path/to/gdal-3.0.4/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_tables_12`
path/to/gdal-3.0.4/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress_12`
```

...

It continues on like this for some amount of lines all starting with `jpeg` and ending with `12` and different words in between. It finally ends with:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [GNUmakefile:82: gdalinfo] Error 1
make: *** [GNUmakefile:112: apps-target] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what to do or what this error even means. If anyone has any ideas, or if there is anymore information I can share, let me know.

Comment: Probably you do not need 12 bit jpeg so disable it. If you want to have it perhaps this wiki page is still valid https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/TIFF12BitJPEG

Comment: How do I disable it? Sorry this is my first time installing a source file, playing around with make files and trying to configure things myself.

Comment: Perhaps it is disabled by editing nmake.opt https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/nmake.opt.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I tried commenting out everything suggested in nmake.opt, but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running my commands, if you run

```bsh
sudo make clean
 ./configure --with-libtiff=internal --with-geotiff=internal --with-jpeg=internal --with-jpeg12
sudo make install
```

Then my error cleared up. Of course, I suspect one would need the right libjpeg packages installed as well. I may have had them installed beforehand so it's something to keep in mind.

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/TIFF12BitJPEG

The above link was extremely useful in solving this issue.